# Servlet API versus REST API

Tags: rest, servlets

I am working with a CRM System that provides two types of APIs: servlet API & REST API, both of  which are over HTTP.

I used to integrate with REST API from my ASP.NET MVC web application by calling the REST URL and manipulating the returned JSON or XML. But I cannot figure out what is meant by a servlet API and can these APIs be called over the web from my ASP.NET MVC application or these APIs should be called inside a Java application?

Sorry if my question seems trivial to someone.

Comment: If only we knew which CRM system it is, we could read the documentation and try to understand. But a servlet API is indeed not very clear. The fact that it's implemented using servlets is irrelevant. What matters is the protocol used to call it, what it takes as arguments and how, and what it returns.

Comment: the solution is "ManageEngine Service deskPlus" version 8.1.

Comment: Read this page of the documentation. The differences and features of both APIs are clearly explained: http://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/help/adminguide/index.html

Comment: so they mentioned that servlet API is a form based input submission by the external applications, so does this mean that i can not call the servlet API from an asp.net form.. i am not sure if this is the case ?

Comment: Why couldn't you? As long as you send a request to the appropriate URL, with the appropriate method and parameters, everything will be ine. An HTTP request is an HTTP request. The CRM doesn't care if you use asp.net, Java, perl or COBOL to send the request.

Answer (score 2):

The Java Servlet API refers to a set of classes used to implement server side programs. The main player is [the Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html):

> A servlet is a small Java program that runs within a Web server. Servlets receive and respond to requests from Web clients, usually across HTTP, the HyperText Transfer Protocol.

If you want a very simplistic analogy, the Servlet is Java's version of [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) (Common Gateway Interface).

A REST API is a way to build applications by fully using the architecture of the web. Leaving all details of REST aside and grossly simplifying, it's basically a HTTP API.

If you want to build a HTTP API, you can use Servlets. So you can also use servlets to build a REST API although there are better alternatives to that (e.g. [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services)) because servlets are a "low level" component and nothing shields you from all the boiler plate code you need to write.

You can of course call a Java application build on top of the Servlet API from other clients (e.g. from ASP.NET MVC). That's what it was built for. For this reason I don't really understand what exactly your CRM system means by a Servlet API and (a separate!?) REST API... so maybe ask the CRM provider?

**EDIT :** Based on what I've read about the ManageEngine Service deskPlus APIs, I'm thinking that this is just an unfortunate name chosen by the provider.

As I mentioned in my comments, when you say [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API you already provide some information from the beginning. Most people, when told about REST understand that you have some abstract resources, that these resources can have multiple representations (JSON, XML, whatever), that each resource is identified by a URI, that `/customers` is referring to a list of customers resources, that `/customers/1` is a customer and that `/customers/2` is another one, that you use `GET /customers/1` to find out details about the customer and `DELETE /customers/1` to delete it etc.

REST is one way to interact with an application, another one is to expose operations that can be called by clients, for example like what [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) is doing. Before REST became the new kid in town people were doing stuff with SOAP. Unlike accessing resources, SOAP is focused on accessing operations. When you mention SOAP to someone she knows that it's a protocol that can use HTTP's POST to transmit messages around, that each message has an XML payload that contains the operation name to invoke and the parameters needed for the call etc.

But even before SOAP and REST becoming widely known, people realized that they can use a form submit to sneak in [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) calls through HTTP. The HTTP form based submission is one of the methods of the API in ManageEngine Service deskPlus. But the form based submission method (as far as I know) doesn't have a cool name like SOAP or REST... so maybe that's why it was named after the Servlet API?! (I'm once again emphasizing that this is just the server implementation which is not important in the context of the HTTP protocol).

So to conclude: Yes, you CAN call the ManageEngine Service deskPlus Servlet API from ASP.NET, even a web browser or any kind of HTTP capable client.

Comment: thanks for the reply, then the Servlet API is a type of REST API, and i have the same question why there are two types of API  ??

Comment: @John Peter: The fact that it's a Servlet API is irrelevant (that's just the implementation). The protocol is the important bit, and that's HTTP. REST is also implemented (mostly) over HTTP, so I don't understand why there are two HTTP APIs. A REST API has some rules to it: you use all the HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, ...), you have identifiers for all your resources, it's stateless etc. If you say Servlet API you do not communicate anything other than it accepts requests and provides a response. What's important is what is in those requests and responses! It might be a form of RPC...

Comment: ... where you call some operations on the server using GET then change it using POST (something like a legacy form of SOAP). It could be anything! As @JB Nizet mentioned, if we knew which CRM system it is, we could read the documentation and try to understand... so which CRM is it? If it's a proprietary one then ask the provider why the two API's or maybe add some more details to your question...

Comment: the solution is "ManageEngine Service deskPlus" version 8.1.